# How to render react component after hitting browser reload button

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm having trouble deploying my react app on Vultr using Ubuntu 16.04 Nginx!

I was able to set it up to get the majority down. For example, I can navigate my react app on my Vultr with my given IP address and a port number. When my react app loads, I can navigate client and server side using express.

But when I navigate to a particular route '/show' which is a get request pulling information from the database, and when I hit the reload button, it displays the data (in json format) being pulled from mysql instead of displaying or rendering the actual component!

Here's the following code that I have:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');

const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let mysql = require('./db');

require('dotenv').config();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

/** Get data from database **/
app.get('/show', (req, res) => {


  // Select data from database

  mysql.query("SELECT * FROM posts", (error, rows) => {

    if(error){
      res.send("An error has occurred.");
    } else {

      if(rows.length > 0){


        res.json(rows);


      } else {
        res.json({result: "No Posts"});
      }

    }

  });

});

/** Post data to the data base - AddPost.js **/
app.post('/add', (req,res) => {

  /** Create local variables and grab user input values **/

  let postTitle = req.body.post_title;
  let postMessage = req.body.post_msg;

  //console.log(`Title: ${postTitle}`, `Message: ${postMessage}`);

  mysql.query("INSERT INTO posts (post_title, post_message) VALUES (?, ?)",[postTitle, postMessage], (error, rows) => {

    if(error){

      res.json({result: error});

    } else {

      if(rows.affectedRows > 0){

        console.log("Data inserted successfully!");

        res.json({result: "Data saved!"});

        //res.redirect('/show');

      } else {

        res.json({result: "An error has occurred."});

      }

    }

  });

});

app.get('/edit/:id', (req, res)=>{

  let id = req.params.id;

  console.log("from back-end server id is " + id);

  // Select data from database

  mysql.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?", [id], (error, rows) => {

    if(error){
      res.send("An error has occurred.");
    } else {

      if(rows.length === 1){

        res.json(rows);

      } else {
        res.json({result: "No Posts"});
      }

    }

  });


});

app.put('/edit/:id', (req, res)=>{

  let id = req.params.id;

  let postTitle = req.body.post_title;
  let postMsg   = req.body.post_message;

  let postObj   = {post_title: postTitle, post_message: postMsg}

  console.log("from back-end server id is for editPost " + id);

  // Select data from database

  mysql.query("UPDATE posts SET ? WHERE id = ?", [postObj, id], (error, rows) => {

    if(error){
      res.json({result: "An error has occurred."});
    } else {

      if(rows.changedRows === 1){

        res.json(rows);

      } else {
        console.log(rows);
        res.json({result: "No changes made."});
      }

    }

  });


});

app.delete('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {

  let id = req.params.id;

  console.log("from back-end server id is for deletePost " , id);

  mysql.query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ?", [id], (error, rows) => {

    if(error){
      res.json({result: "An error has occurred."});
    } else {

      if(rows.affectedRows === 1){

        res.json(rows);

      } else {
        res.json({result: "An error has occurred."});
      }
// <CustomPagination activePage={activePage} posts={posts.length} postPerPage={postPerPage} />
    }

  });
});

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  });
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 7000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import NavigationBar from "./components/NavigationBar";
import Home from './components/Home';
import AddPost from './components/AddPost';
import ShowPosts from "./components/ShowPosts";
import EditPost from "./components/EditPost";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

          <NavigationBar />
        <br />
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home} />
            <Route exact path={"/add"} component={AddPost} />
            <Route exact path={"/show"} component={ShowPosts} />
            <Route exact path={"/edit/:id"} component={EditPost} />
        </Switch>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

On my route '/show' I have a table displaying the data that is coming from the database, but when I reload the browser, it doesn't display the component but the actual data instead.

Is there a work around with this issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: usually for backend apis like this, you use /api/ to prefix all routes -- that way it doesn't conflict. So something like `app.get('/api/show', (req, res) => {...}`. I believe there's a better way to structure it in an express app though, so someone else might have a better answer.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your answer and it worked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get('/show', (req, res) => {   

 res.json(rows);
```

This returns the data from the SQL rows and the end-point is called shows. I think you need to differentiate between the API shows and the path shows within app.js,

```
<Route exact path={"/show"} component={ShowPosts} />
```

So maybe:

```
app.get('api/show', (req, res) => {}
```

Then within ShowPosts get the data from api/show

```
var component = <ShowPosts data={get data from api/show} />
<Route exact path={"/show"} component={component} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also tried your code and it worked! :)